# Strange Behaviour in Swift: constant defined with LET but behaving like a variable defined with VAR

Tags: reference, swift

Stuck on the below for a day! Any insight would be greatly appreciated. The constant in the first block `match0` behaves as expected. The constant defined in the second block does not behave as nicely in the face of a change to its "source":

```
var str = "+y+z*1.0*sum(A1:A3)"

if let range0 = str.rangeOfString("^\\+|^\\-|^\\*|^\\/", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch){

    let match0 = str[range0]
    println(match0) //yields "+" - as expexted

    str.removeRange(range0)
    println(match0) //yields "+" - as expected

    str.removeRange(range0)
    println(match0) //yields "+" - as expected
}

if let range1 = str.rangeOfString("^\\+|^\\-|^\\*|^\\/", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch){
    let match1 = str[range1]
    println(match1) //yields "+" as expected
    str.removeRange(range1)
    println(match1) //!@#$ OMG!!!!!!!!!!! a constant variable has changed! This prints "z"
}
```

The following are the options I can see:

1. `match1` has somehow obtained a reference to its source instead of being copied by value [Problem: Strings are value types in Swift]
2. `match1` has somehow obtained a closure to its source instead of just being a normal constant/variable? [Problem: sounds like science fiction & then why does match0 behave so well?]
3. Could there be a bug in the Swift compiler? [Problem: Experience has taught me that this is very very very rarely the solution to your problem...but it is still in beta]

Comment: Note: removeRange is a mutating function.

My guess is that under the covers match1 is a pointer to the string which just changed.

Comment: The two examples behave in the same way. The difference is that the first block deletes a Character **twice** and the 1st and 3rd characters are both "+" so the example results are confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a compiler optimization bug. In the swift language guide it says:

> Behind the scenes, Swift’s compiler optimizes string usage so that
>   actual copying takes place only when absolutely necessary. This means
>   you always get great performance when working with strings as value
>   types.

I dug around a little and found that it's possible to get the memory address of a string via `str._core._baseAddress` *(Note: that's probably supposed to be a `private` var in swift's core lib, but it seems to have been overlooked)*.

If I modify the original code to print the address of `str` and `match0`/`match1`, this is what I get:

```
+    str address: 0x0000000100006130; match0 address: 0x0000000100006130
+    str address: 0x0000000100511f70; match0 address: 0x0000000100006130
+    str address: 0x0000000100511f70; match0 address: 0x0000000100006130
+    str address: 0x0000000100511f70; match1 address: 0x0000000100511f70
z    str address: 0x0000000100511f70; match1 address: 0x0000000100511f70
```

Notice how the first one prints the same address since no copy needed to be made yet but, once the first `str.removeRange(range0)` is called, the addresses change because it copies `str` to a new location.

That last one is the problem. From what I can tell, the compiler *should* have copied `str` to a new memory location when `str.removeRange(range1)` was called, but it didn't (bug). Since it didn't, `str` and `match1` still have the same base address so `match1` ends up printing "z".

Sounds like it might be [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com) time.

---

### Update: Workaround

It looks like an easy workaround to this is to force the compiler to trigger a string copy by calling `stringByAppendingString("")` before the second `rangeOfString` call:

```
var str = "+y+z*1.0*sum(A1:A3)"

if let range0 = str.rangeOfString("^\\+|^\\-|^\\*|^\\/", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch){
    // ...
}

// Force a string copy by appending an empty string to get around optimization bug
str = str.stringByAppendingString("") 

if let range1 = str.rangeOfString("^\\+|^\\-|^\\*|^\\/", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch){
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: `removeRange` is a `mutating` function.

For the 1st `if` block `str` = "+y+z*1.0*sum(A1:A3)"
For the 2nd `if` block `str` = "+z*1.0*sum(A1:A3)"

If prior to the 2nd `if` block you reinitialize `str`

```
str = "+y-z*1.0*sum(A1:A3)"
```

you get the result you expect: "+".

This seems to bear out what @Mike S wrote.